# The carriage won't take me even when I'm naked, what do I need to do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was at Winterhelm and encumbered. I figured that the carriage had to be quicker so I hired the thing and paid my 20 gold. Guy said hop aboard so I did.  The guy then said ok I am ready when you are.

Now there was no option I could see to talk to the guy anymore but there was the `E` to use carriage.  I clicked that and my character got *off* the cart.  Clicked `E` and it got back on but that was it.  Spoke to the guy and nothing obvious.

Then I had the brilliant idea the developers didn't want you to bypass weight and that if encumbered you were stuck so I save, got buck naked and still nada. So, what do I need to do to get the carriage to actually get me to a destination?

Comment: Is the gold removed from your inventory?

Comment: There's a hard to pin down bug where some game components don't update your encumberance rating.  I don't know if it's the case in this case, but entering and leaving a building usually fixes it for me.  You could enter and leave the stables for example after dropping enough to become unencumbered.

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't take you anywhere if you were naked.

Comment: Wait are you in Windhelm or Winterhold?

Answer (score 15):

**Using a carriage:** Talk to the guy, tell him where you want to go, walk to the backside of the carriage, look at the steps, and when the action-thingy pops up, activate it. Your character then will climb on by him/herself and gold is removed and the journey begins.

**BUT**: It is a fundamental rule in Skyrim that **you** ***cannot fast-travel if you are carrying to much weight.***

Since travelling on a carriage "beams" you, after a loading screen, to your desired destination, it counts as fast-travelling. 
I love it that you got butt-naked **( :D )** but if you kept your armor in your inventory, you were still carrying the armor, thus carrying its weight. In order to be able to fast-travel (or use the carriage) you have to drop enough of the stuff in your inventory so you are no longer encumbered (I learned a new word, thank you! )

I have not tried it, but maybe drinking a potion of strength (increases your carrying-capacity for a certain amount, depending on the quality of the potion) and then using the carriage might help. But with the potion I'm just gessing. But if you drop enough weight, the carriage will take you where ever you want to go.

Comment: _you cannot fast-travel if you are carrying to much weight_ - except if you're on your horse :).

Comment: Drinking a potion of strength always lets me fast travel.

Comment: @user28982 That's because after you've drunk the potion, you're no longer "carrying too much weight".

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to cheat the system is to get on a horse. Then it lets me fast travel I don't know why it just does.

Comment: because the horse is a pack mule.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to hire him after you drop your things and are no longer carrying too much stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) that will allow you to adjust your maximum encumbrance weight.

Hit <kbd>~</kbd> to enter the console, then type the following and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`player.modav carryweight 99999999`

You can, of course, put whatever number you'd like in the final place. Be careful not to make it too big, or you may cause bugs.

Answer (score -1):

You could also drink a potion of strength which adds to your carrying weight... but I used the horse thing too.